# Compare 2 files in unix file1(2M numbers/rows/lines) , file2(2,000,480 numbers/rows/lines)

Tags: unix, compare

How can I compare this 2 big files in unix.

I've already tried using 'grep -Fxvf file1.txt file2.txt | wc -l' but the output is 2,000,480 and when switching file1 and file2 the output is 1,999,999.

How can I get the output of '480' because that's what i am expecting.

I've also tried using diff/cmp commands but the output is too complicated.

Comment: Why do you expect both operations (switching file1 and file2) to return equal results? Seems that file2.txt has more patterns which show up only in file2 and not in file1. When switching the file name arguments, it will trying to find patterns in file1 which do not show in file2, and those might be less in their count.

Comment: Hi sramij, i just tried switching file 1 and file2. I've also tried it on my own way. See below.

file 1:

apple
orange
kiwi

file2:

kiwi
apple
pakwan

then grep -Fvxf file1 file2 the output is pakwan. So i think that when i use the same command on the scenario above. i will have a '480' as my output. Am i right?

Thank you!

Comment: make 2 files with 5-6 records each, including non-members in both files. Get that to work, THEN confirm it is really working with your larger files. Also you mentioned diff and cmp, but `man comm` may show you some other ideas. If you edit your Q with the small sample files I'm recommending, people will help you out immediately. Also indicate your expected output given the 2 inputs. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an absolute value of a difference in line numbers in 2 files. You can achieve it easily with `awk` and get a decent result. You'd read numbers of lines in an array and later subtract the array values in the `END` block. For pure shell it'd have to get more complex. Imagine you get some test data generated (10 and 14 line files):

```
$ seq 1 10 > ten
$ seq 1 14 > fourteen
```

And then you do:

```
$ ( wc -l ten ; wc -l fourteen ) | awk '{ print $1}' | sort -rn | xargs -J % echo % - p | dc
```

The result:

```
4
```

But much better way would be do just do it in 3 lines (get word count for `file1`, then `file2` and then subtract)